# print a struct within a struct golang

Tags: go, struct

I want to print a certain item within a struct, that is within a struct. Example:
**Pretend I have made up a blueprint struct, and are making an new one**
**Pretend I have a myshapes struct, that contains a title, # of circles, and squares**

```
car := blueprints{
dots: 5,
lines: 25,
shapes: []myshapes{
    myshapes{
        title:"car #1",
        circles:5,
        squares:7,
    },
    myshapes{
        title:"car #2",
        circles:2,
        squares:14,
    },
}
```

How do I print:

```
title:"car #1"
circles:5
squares:7
title:"car #2"
circles:2
squares:14
```

Comment: Let's not pretend or guess what types`blueprint` and `myshapes` are: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below shows how you'd print a particular field value of a struct:

```
type child struct {
    name string
    age int
}

type parent struct {
    name string
    age int
    children child
}

func main() {
    family := parent{
        name: "John",
        age: 40,
        children: child{
            name: "Johnny",
            age: 10,
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(family.children.name); // Prints "Johnny"
}
```

The code above would print "Johnny", which is a value of a struct within the parent struct. The code doesn't make much sense, however, because the field is `children`, yet there is only ever able to be one child as its value.

Let's leverage slices. Now that we know how to print a particular value, all we would need for your case is to loop over a slice and print the same way we did above.

We can do that like this:

```
type child struct {
    name string
    age int
}

type parent struct {
    name string
    age int
    children []child
}

func main() {
    family := parent{
        name: "John",
        age: 40,
        children: []child{
            child{
                name: "Johnny",
                age: 10,
            },
            child{
                name: "Jenna",
                age: 7,
            },
        },
    }

    for _, child := range family.children {
        fmt.Println(child.name);
    }
}
```

The above example will pront "Johnny" and "Jenna".

You can use a similar pattern to what I showed above in your own code to loop through your structs and print whatever value your heart desires :)

---

**Keep in mind**, there are many ways to loop through things. For example, all the following loops would print "Johnny" and "Jenna" from the examples above.

```
for _, child:= range family.children{ // Prints "Jonny" and "Jenna"
    fmt.Println(child.name); 
}

for i, _ := range family.children{ // Prints "Jonny" and "Jenna"
    fmt.Println(family.children[i].name);
}

for i := 0; i < len(family.children); i++ { // Prints "Jonny" and "Jenna"
    fmt.Println(family.children[i].name);
}
```